# How to make taskbar look identical between two monitors

Tags: windows, multi-monitor

I work with a dual-monitor setup and I am just wondering what sorts of utilities are out there to make the taskbar of my secondary monitor look identical to my primary monitor?

Any info is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Windows 10 sorry

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to know what version of Windows you are using and how identical you need the taskbars to be.  Windows 10 has this ability by default, although I'm not sure if it shows EVERYTHING the same on both bars (I can check tomorrow).  Prior to Windows 7/10, I used to use [UltraMon by Realtimesoft](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon), for managing multiple monitors and windows and taskbars.  Ultramon is a fairly good and inexpensive program for managing multiple monitors and definitely had taskbar mirroring. Once Windows 7 came out, I no longer used Ultramon, but that was only because I was using it for minimal functionality.  It does a LOT more.

See their page on [SmartTaskbars](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/smart_taskbar.asp) for more info.

Ultramon is free for 30 days, and is $40 US after that.

Update:  Now that I'm back on my multi-display setup, it looks like the built-in Windows 10 feature has three options: (accessed by right clicking the taskbar and going to taskbar settings, and then scrolling down to the multiple displays section)

1. show tasks on all taskbars
2. show tasks on primary taskbar and on taskbar where window is open
3. only show tasks on taskbar where window is open.

It also shows the start button and the time on the other taskbars.
Pinned items appear to be limited to the primary taskbar, as well as the notification area and the area with items like network connection and volume control.

If you just want basic functionality where all tasks are on all taskbars, the Windows 10 feature is probably sufficient.

If you want more control, check out [Ultramon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon)

Comment: "`Windows 10 has this ability by default`" - can you tell us how? Thanks

Comment: Right click the taskbar, taskbar properties.  If you scroll down, there is a section on multiple displays and what should be shown on what taskbar.  As the OP didn't provide much information yet, I'm not sure if this is all he needs or if something like Ultramon is required.

Comment: I don't see it on Windows 7, in the office, but will try on Windows 10 when I get home. Thanks; this is sure to help a lot of people

Comment: It may be new to Windows 10.  I can check on a Windows 7 VM in a bit, but if you can't find it, it's probably not in 7.  I mentioned 7 because I used to use Ultramon to handle things like moving windows between monitors and some other functions that it provides.  I believe Windows 7 introduced a multi-monitor taskbar, but without many options.  It was enough for what I needed though.  Again, I'll spin up a VM in a bit and check.

Comment: No need. It is a"nice to have" feature, not "must have" ;-) And more often than not I have Windows on monitor 1 & a Linux VM on monitor 2,